# The sum $\sum_{t \not \mod - 1} \chi[t(t + 1)]$

Tags: number-theory, gauss-sums

It's from Multiplicative Number Theory, Davenport,
pp. 24.

In calculating $\tau^{2}$ where
\[
\tau = \sum_{x = 1}^{q - 1} \chi(n)e_{q}(x),
\]
$\chi(n)$ Dirichlet character mod 3 and $e_{q}(x) = e^{2 \pi i x/ q}$,
I see a step which I can't understand.

It is easy to see that
\[
\sum_{t} \chi(t(1 + t)) = A + B\omega + C \omega^{2}.
\] 
But how can we verify that
\[
\sum_{t} \chi(t(1 + t)) = A + B\omega,
\] 
where $\omega$ is a cubic root of unity?

Wouldn't cubic roots of unity be linearly
independent of one another?

Comment: For a cubic root of unity $\omega\neq 1$ you have $w^2+w+1=0$.

Comment: It's really helpful. Thanks.